# How would I use Mathematica to solve this question?

Tags: linear-algebra, homework, application

Given the following matrix, A, that corresponds to a particular subset of the world wide web:

```
A = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

How would I solve the following question?

[image]

Here is what I have done so far:

I have found the transition matrix, P, for the PageRank algorithm corresponding to A, with damping factor δ = 0.85 using the following:

```
n = 30;
delta = 0.85;
P = Transpose[Table[(1 - delta)/n + 
 delta A[[i, j]]/(Sum[A[[i, k]], {k, 1, n}]), {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
 n}]];
MatrixForm[P]
```

Then I believe I have been able to solve parts (d) - (g), using the following:

d)

```
mu = Table[1/n, {i, 1, n}];
Ordering[MatrixPower[P, 2].mu]
```

e)

```
mu = Table[1/n, {i, 1, n}];
Ordering[MatrixPower[P, 5].mu]
```

f)

```
mu = Table[1/n, {i, 1, n}];
Ordering[MatrixPower[P, 10].mu]
```

g)

```
q = Eigenvectors[P][[1]];
Ordering[q]
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear -at least not to me- what you are asking here. Also, it would be really helpful if you could post the matrix in code-form so people can copy-paste it easily, rather that the photo you have uploaded

Comment: Am I right in assuming that your only problem is to generate vector $\mathbf{\mu}$, for points (a-c) $\mathbf{\mu}$ is a vector of the kind $(1,0,\ldots)$ and for (d-g) $\mathbf{\mu}=1/30(1,1,\ldots)$?

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0, I'm asking how to solve this question and have shown some of the workings I've got so far. Thank you for the tip though about making the matrix code instead of a picture.

Comment: @yarchik, I'm not sure about the whole question in general, but what you have said is what I'm trying to do. I have provided some of workings so far but don't know if it is correct.

Comment: This question is a big improvement over the original version. Showing work, as code rather than an image, and noting where things are stuck, are both really important.

Comment: The easiest way to construct `mu` for parts (a)–(c) is `Prepend[ConstantArray[0,29], 1]`.  I don't know enough about this field to know whether your answers are correct, though.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. Thank you so much, rather than just expecting answers as such, I'm willing to take on feedback to improve my question and by showing my working also, it allows me to share my knowledge with others. Also do you know if what I have done thus far is correct?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, what you have provided is helpful. All good, thank you though.

Comment: The matrix powering looks fine. I know essentially nothing about PageRank computations so I cannot say much beyond that.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. That's alright all good. Thank you again though, you have been helpful.